# why does the cancel button in web view do not work when open iTunes App Store url appears. (for understanding)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, ios11

Is it because a cancel button method is not implemented?

[circled in blue cancel button not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDt4I.png)

Below is my code. Where user is informed through a alert view that an updated version is available. Should OK be clicked, it would direct them to the app in iTunes App Store. (as shown in the pic below) However when cancel is clicked, nothing happens.

```
-(void)showAlert {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"New Version Available on Appstore" message:@"Please update app to continue" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        NSURL *iTunesLink = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8"];
        [application openURL:iTunesLink options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                 NSLog(@"Opened url");
            }
        }];
            //button click event
                        }];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I manage to resolve this by adding "itms-apps" (straight away redirected to appstore with no cancel button). But I would still like to understand why the cancel button do not work

Since the cancel button in the web view is not created by me, is it possible to add a method to that?

My apologies for not being clear in my question. I would like to know why the circled cancel button in the screenshot do not work.

Comment: Screen shot makes no sense. It shows the App Store app, not _your_ app with _your_ alert. The Cancel button in the screen shot is not your Cancel button. Your Cancel button works just fine.

Comment: Thanks matt Yup my cancel button in my alert view works fine. However I would like to know why the cancel button in the screen shot (circled) do not work and not why the cancel button in my alert view do not work.

Comment: But that is not your cancel button. It is not your app. It has nothing to do with you.

Comment: Yes I understand it has nothing to do with me. But I would like to understand or find out why it is not working or if it is possible to add a method to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an UIAlertController you can add to it different buttons as UIAlertActions that will do something when each one gets clicked. You will have to specify what you want to happen by implementing the handler in the initialization of the UIAlertAction (like you did above for the OK action).

If you pass nil as the handler the alert will simply be dismissed, but nothing else will happen because you did not tell it to do anything else.

The cancel button is related to the click on the alert button, not anything that you do after you click a different button, as maybe you'd like in you case.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller?language=objc).

Comment: Hi Elvereth, the cancel button in the alert view is working fine. Even if I add a action to it. for example if the cancel button in the alert view is tap, segue to another viewcontroller it works. However if I were to click on OK, a web view of the App Store would be shown with a cancel and store button. The store button works but the cancel button do not. Hence I would like to know why the circled cancel button is not working. And if I would like it to work, how do I go about adding a method to it.

Comment: You cannot implement or pass any method to be execute when the cancel button of the App Store page opened in the WebView is clicked. As you say in the comments above this page has nothing to do with you, you cannot modify the behavior on the click on that button, it's simply not possible.

By the way I can't see the image of the button anymore, but my point remain: you can only tell the device what to do when the buttons created by you are clicked.